# Ngrx - Observe some elements inside store

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

Let's suppose I have an interface

```
export interface INotification {
    id: number;
    DateReceived: number;
    Title: string;
    Message: string;
    Tipology: string;
    isRead: number;
}
```

and a reducer system. In my component I Could make and Observer

```
public notifications: Observable<INotification[]>;
constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
   this.notifications = this.store.select<any>('notifications');
}
```

That's quite ok if my intent is just to show the elements in page like so..

```
<div *ngFor="let notification of notifications | async">
     <div class="centralItem">
       <p>
         <b>{{notification.Title}}
         </b>
       </p>
       <div [innerHtml]="notification.Message">
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**The Problem:** I would like to observe all the *Notifications* inside my store that has the property **isRead** equals to **0** to count all those elements and put a *badge* like the image below: 
[image]

Tryed many ways but i'm unable to map, filter, and i don't know what exactly i have to do to observe those items.. sorry i'm new with ngrx and all the observable pattern in JS - Typescript.
Thanks.

EDIT: My Reducer:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store'
import { INotification } from './../models/notification.model'
import * as NotificationActions from './../actions/notification.actions'


export function reducer(state: INotification[] = [], action: NotificationActions.Actions) {
    console.log(action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case NotificationActions.ADD_NOTIFICATION:
            return [...state, action.payload].sort(compare);
        case NotificationActions.REMOVE_NOTIFICATION:
            state.splice(action.payload, 1).sort(compare);
            return state;
        case NotificationActions.REMOVE_NOTIFICATIONS_BY_TIPOLOGY:
            return state.map(val => val.Tipology != action.payload).sort(compare);
        default:
            return state.sort(compare);
    }

    function compare(a, b) {
        const aDate = a.DateReceived;
        const bDate = b.DateReceived;

        let comparison = 0;
        if (aDate > bDate) {
            comparison = -1;
        } else if (aDate < bDate) {
            comparison = 1;
        }
        return comparison;
    }
}
```

My AppState:

```
import { INotification } from '../models/notification.model';

export interface AppState {
    readonly notification: INotification[];
}
```

My NgModule:

```
NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AuthLoader
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    StoreModule.forRoot({ notifications: reducer })
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AuthLoader
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
  ]
})
```

**SOLVED:**
By now the best i can do is so:

```
    public counter = 0;
     ngOnInit() {
        this.notifications.subscribe((notifs) => {
        this.counter = 0;
          notifs.forEach(elem => {
            if (elem.isRead == 0)
              this.counter++;
          });
        });
      }
```

Looks like a little dirty but works XD

```
<ion-badge item-end *ngIf='counter > 0'>{{counter}}</ion-badge>
```

Comment: Post the reducer and the `NgModule` where you provide your `StoreModule`.

Comment: Edited with reducer, appstate and ngModule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a subscription on the notificationsObservable like :

```
public hasNotifications: boolean;
ngOnInit() {
   this.notifications.subscribe( notifs => {
      this.hasNotifications = notifs.some( el => !el.isRead);
   });
}
```

then use it like this on your element which should have a badge (basic html which can perhaps not reflect your case, but just to explain...) :

```
<div class="badge-holder">
  <span *ngIf="hasNotification">MyBadge</span>
</div>
```